# Asterisks in the output of R describe function

Tags: r, statistics, psych, describe

What does it mean the asterisk next to some item names in the descriptive statistics table given by describe function (package psych) in R ?

```
                       vars  n    mean    sd 
STUDY_ID*                 1 67    1.00  0.00
COUNTRY_ID*               2 67    1.00  0.00
EXTRACTION_DATE*          3 67   34.00 19.49
SITE_ID                   4 67    8.94  5.30
SUBJECT_ID*               5 67   34.00 19.49
SUBJECT_REF*              6 67   34.00 19.49
REF_I1_CENTERINFO         7 67    8.94  5.30
REF_NUMBER                8 67    9.21  7.09
REF_I1_NOM*               9 67    8.03  5.62
REF_I1_PRENOM*           10 67    8.22  4.95
RANDOMIZATION_R1*        11 66    1.50  0.50
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: Perhaps the asterisks allow to distinguish character variables from numeric variables

Comment: could you please post your example in a text format rather than as an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?psych::describe`:

> If the check option is TRUE, variables that are categorical or
> logical are converted to numeric and then described.  These
> variables are marked with an * in the row name.